# super viewWillAppear:animated vs super viewWillAppear:YES

Tags: super

It seems to be a simple question, but I'm not sure what's the difference between

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Can anyone explain it please? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the former, you let the caller decide whether the view will appear animated, in the latter you force the superclass to appear animated.

Broadly, the latter isn't very good programming practice because the caller can't rely on their intent (specifically the case where animation *isn't* wanted) being honored.

It's probably worth noting that if your subclass is the immediate subclass of `UIViewController`, the calls are effectively identical because `UIViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` method does nothing.

EDIT:

I almost hate to add this because as I say it's bad programming practice, but I've seen the syntax of passing `YES` to the superclass in a few cases where the intent of the developer was to say, *"This view controller should only ever be shown animated."*

But, as I say, it's a bad practice since it breaks subclassing.

I think a much better thing to do if you're thinking along these lines is to use an assert or at least a log message, e.g.:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    NSAssert(animated, @"This view controller should always be shown animated, but wasn't");
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

Then you catch the erroneous use in testing (where you'll immediately discover you *do* have a non-animated use-case).

Comment: So in what case should I pass a concrete value to the superclass?

Comment: You pass the concrete value when you push the view controller, so for example as an argument to `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.  Then `viewWillAppear:` will be called by the OS with that value.  You don't call `viewWillAppear:` directly.

Comment: In other words, you should never pass a concrete value to the superclass.  You should always pass the `animated` argument.